# php echo not working properly

Tags: php, html, echo, forms, http-post

Basically, I want made a simple form in html and i want to output the all of the user input once clicked submit using php. So far its just displaying the details I entered but it doesn't get user's data to echo them out. Here are my two files

output.php:

```
<?php 
echo 'Name: '.$POST["name"].'<br /> Gender: '.$POST["gender"].'<br />Country: '.$POST["country"];
?>
```

testingformphp.html (form part):

```
    <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="./PHP/output.php"/>
    Name<input name="name" type="text" id="name"/><br/>

    Gender<label><input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender_0" value="male"/>Male</label><br/>
    <label><input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender_1" value="female"/>Female</label><br/>

<select name="country" id="select">
    <optgroup title="europe">
    <option value="Russia">Russia</option>
    <option value="Greece">Greece</option>


    </optgroup>

    </select>


    <input type="submit" id="button" value="Submit"/>
    <input type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset"/>

    </form>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: it's `$_POST` not `$POST`

Comment: Also don't echo raw user input, pass it through `htmlspecialchars()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$POST does not exists, try $_POST.

Comment: Thanks! but now it's working but is not displaying the Country value for some reason

Comment: make sure the value is in the array. do a `print_r($_POST);`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
echo 'Name: '.$_POST["name"].'<br /> Gender: '.$_POST["gender"].'<br />Country: '.$_POST["country"];
?>
```

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php       To review the post and get method.